# Module is not loaded, while running python script from terminal

Tags: python

I wrote a script which runs perfectly from Pycharm. But if i run this code from terminal it says no module is found.

Here is the code:

```
from rplidar import RPLidar, RPLidarException

lidar = RPLidar('/dev/ttyUSB0')

info = lidar.get_info()
print(info)

health = lidar.get_health()
print(health)

try:
    for i, scan in enumerate(lidar.iter_scans()):
        scan_data = []
        for d in scan:          #d[0] : Quality of the measurement
            '''if 0< d[1] <15:     #d[1] : Angle of the measurement
                print(d[2]/10)  #d[2] : Distance of the measurement '''



        if False:
            lidar.stop()
            lidar.stop_motor()
            lidar.disconnect()
            break
except KeyboardInterrupt as err:
    print('key board interupt')
    lidar.stop()
    lidar.stop_motor()
    lidar.disconnect()

except RPLidarException as err:
    print(err)
    lidar.stop()
    lidar.stop_motor()
    lidar.disconnect()
except AttributeError:
    print('hi attribute error')
```

while i run this scipt as bellow:

```
python -m main.py
```

i got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/home/shahin/PycharmProjects/RpLidar/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from rplidar import RPLidar, RPLidarException
ImportError: No module named rplidar
shahin@shahin-UX360UAK:~/PycharmProjec
```

I will be so glad if you tell me how to overcome this problem.

And in the meantime, when i run this code in pycharm i want to catch KeyboardInterrupt from it. But its not working. Even i do Contro + c.

Can somebody tell me who to do KeyboardInterrupt in pycharm as well.

Comment: Do you maybe use different Python versions or installations?

Comment: Seems like some problem with python and module installation path. Check if you're using the right path to the module to work in terminal.

Comment: What version of python are you using, and where is it located?

Comment: Hi, even though i installed 3.7 but in my termial it shows Python 2.7.15rc1 (default, Apr 15 2018, 21:51:34) @user8408080

Comment: But same code is working properly while i run it from pycharm should it also work properly while i run this from terminal? @Shiv_90

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to terminal type python3 if it shows python 3.7 then type `python3 -m main.py` or `python3 main.py`

Answer (score -1):

if you read this post, it will significate that you want to communicate with LiDAR in order to integrate it to your project. So, I thinks that my work can interest you, check it at this link : https://github.com/NouriHuseynov/LiDAR_A1M8.git
BR,
Nouri Huseynov

Comment: Please [_always_ disclose your affiliation when mentioning your own work](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion). And please read [answer]. [Link-only answers are discouraged here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/248627).

Comment: Use better English when answering a question. Also, it is better to respect the markdown feature so that your text is well organised and usable for the reader.