# Running python from command line asks me to import modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, python-module

I have a script written in Spyder(Python 3.8) on Linux. While on the Spyder console the script runs fine, while I an calling it from the Linux terminal it seems like it doesn't see the modules I import in the script. Opening the terminal I run: `python3 /zhome/c9/f/144817/Desktop/ChargersDaniel.py`  but, here is the error I take:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  File "/zhome/c9/f/144817/Desktop/ChargersDaniel.py", line 9, in <module>
import GPyOpt ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'GPyOpt'
```

where GPyOpt is the very first library I have at the first lines in my script.
It looks like for some reason, python3 doesn't see the libraries installed. I have checked the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53433787/module-is-not-loaded-while-running-python-script-from-terminal) but that's not my case cause I am already calling Python3 at my terminal.

Any suggestions ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did your editor install your modules in a virutal environment?

Comment: @Talon how I can understand that?

Comment: Your Spider IDE in the bottom bar center might have something like `conda (Python 3.8)` indicating your environment. I strongly suspect if you are in a new shell outside of Sypder you just need to activate the proper conda environment again. The Spyder FAQ has a bunch of entries related to environments. http://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/faq.html

Comment: @JonSG that would actually most probably solve my issue, however, when typing `conda --version` on my terminal I get a "command not found".
The way I open spyder is by using this command `spyder-4.1.5-python-3.8.4-numpy-1.19.2-matplotlib-pandas` which loads all the required dependencies and then opens Spyder IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check if GPyOpt is installed when running from your terminal:

```sh
python3 -c "import GPyOpt"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
  echo "GPyOpt is installed!"
fi
```

Comment: the problem is not this specific library, I actually get the same error for all the libraries I have at the beginning of my script. So, I thought of checking the `sys.path` for both cases (spyder, terminal) to see which site-packages path each one has, and it seems like they look to 2 different directories. Can I actually add the directory which has the required libraries into the PYTHONPATH maybe?

Comment: Yes, I would try setting your terminal `$PATH` to look in the same directory, although you may just need to install the required libraries in terminal if that doesn't work (pip3 install --user <LIBRARY>)